# Setting vs Settings? Which one makes more sense in a dropdown button

Tags: website-design, web-app, copywriting, dropdown, settings

[image: setting button]

This button should do what it looks like it should do. It opens a drop down of actions that a user can perform on their user account. Should I go with "Setting" or "Settings"?

Comment: Would profile or account be a better title? The things you are showing aren't really settings - they tend to be things that change the experience rather than account attributes.

Comment: That's a good point Stewart. I ended up going with Settings. This button only appears in user profile page, so user can understand that the context for settings is about their accounts.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Setting is singular, so use it if you only have one thing to set.

Settings is plural, so use it when you have multiple things to set.  This is likely to be the case most of the time, so **when in doubt, use 'Settings'**

Comment: Can you tell me where in the dictionary you see the word "setting" in singular with this particular meaning?

Comment: @x-yuri Oxford Engilsh Dictionary; Webster's Dictionary; Google's dictionary service; dictonary.com; etc.  Can you find a dictionary that doesn't have a description of "setting" as a noun which is not the action of the verb "set".

Comment: You didn't give a link, so let us consider [this one](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/setting#setting__4). (Or give yours.) There's only one relevant definition there: `settings [plural] the place on a computer or other electronic device where you can choose the way that it works or looks; the particular choices that you make`. But it's marked as not being used in singular. I might very well be wrong, but I believe word "settings" doesn't have singular in this particular context. At least, not "setting." "Setting" in singular form has other nonrelevant meanings.

Comment: @x-yuri The Oxford Learner's Dictionary is a simplified version originally for school children, so you need to take its' definitions in context.   However, this is more about language use so it's probably best to bring it up on English.SE.  Or if you want to discuss it, I'll be happy to give you many links in the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be several things to set. So ***Settings***, plural.